# How to update a table in another database using triggers?

Tags: mysql, triggers, synchronization

I want to update another table in another database, this is for stock quantity, when the quantity field get updated then update the other table.

I have this:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS syncFromStockSys //

CREATE TRIGGER syncFromStockSys BEFORE UPDATE on db1.quantity

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE TABLE db2.oc_product 
    SET  `quantity` = NEW.quantity 
    WHERE SKU = SKU;   //<<-----------
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

But there is an sintax error
I am using phpMyAdmin to acomplish this.

This is the error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'TABLE db2.oc_product
>       SET  `quantity` = NEW.quantity
>       WHERE SKU = NEW.' at line 5

Comment: include the contents of syntax error you receive in your question

Comment: I added the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use PHP myadmin for any serious work. Get yourself a proper mysql client. As for the error. You shouldn't include the delimiter `//` inside the trigger block

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS syncFromStockSys //

CREATE TRIGGER syncFromStockSys BEFORE UPDATE on db1.quantity

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE db2.oc_product 
    SET  `quantity` = NEW.quantity 
    WHERE SKU = SKU; 
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And you probably meant

```
 WHERE SKU = NEW.SKU;
```

Comment: I tried before with no delimiter inside the block and new.sku also; Anyway still not working, any clue about that?

Comment: PPlease never use 'Not working' here on stack overflow. Post the exact error and the involved line numbers

Comment: Ok got it, do you have any idea why this error appear?

Comment: Silly me you have it as `update table` and I missed that completely in my first attempt. See the update

Comment: Yeah that was the issue there, take a look into my other question please, I can not understand why it is happening..

Comment: I have given the answer to that question in another question. So under the rules I cannot post an answer. Please refer to my answer in the duplicate. The trouble is that you can't modify a table inside a trigger if that table is the one that fired the trigger. In your case it's not direct, but happens indirectly

Comment: Sorry I can not understand that, because I do not want to modify the current updated table, just modify an external one